# Uso e origine dell'espressione "Mi è partita una placca"

Tags: meaning, regional, phrase-origin

Ho sentito pronunciare da una conoscente la frase:

> L'altro giorno ero al lavoro e mi hanno fatto veramente partire una
>   placca!

Alla mia richiesta di spiegazioni sull'espressione "partire una placca" mi ha detto che vuol significare *mi hanno fatto arrabbiare*, *mi hanno fatto dare in escandescenze*.

La mia perplessità è legata al fatto che era la prima volta che la sentivo ed inoltre cercando le possibili accezioni di [placca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/placca/) su Treccani e anche sul GDLI non viene fatto cenno a questa espressione.

L'avete mai sentita usare e, in caso affermativo, avete idea da cosa potrebbe nascere questo modo di dire? È per caso un'espressione regionale?

Comment: Interessante! Simile all'espressione "mi si è chiusa la vena", che ho sentito molto di recente. Quest'ultima tuttavia ha già un'origine più intuibile.

Comment: Mai sentita questa versione. Penso sia un uso locale. Io conosco, con significato simile, *mi è partito un embolo*.

Comment: Mai sentita neanch'io, e anch'io ipotizzo un uso (molto) locale.

Answer (score 3):

Per quanto riguarda l'origine, in linea con le ipotesi formulate nei commenti, potrebbe riferirsi ad una placca nel senso di [ateroma](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateroma). Si aggregherebbe dunque alla famiglia di espressioni menzionanti problemi acuti vascolari per indicare reazioni stizzite e/o d'ira.

Seguendo questa linea, azzarderei dire che, essendoci talmente tanta scelta di parole da mettere al posto di placca (e.g. vena, embolo ecc...), più che un regionalismo sembra un'espressione liberamente modificabile da chiunque.